# Wrap text in a column after a character (;) using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

Using [this as a guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/723523/in-sharepoint-online-list-how-to-use-json-to-wrap) I've applied some JSON formatting to the column itself, via List Settings.  This has helped, yet the column is still too wide.  I'd like the text to go to a new line after a ';' character.

How would I achieve this using JSON?

Here's a picture of the list with the text I'd like to format.  (BTW - the column I've indicated is a look-up column).

[image: screenshot of a list, with the field indicated that I wish to format using JSON]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "white-space": "wrap"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

### Update 1 - in response to Ganesh's comment

It's an additional field I've brought across from a different list, it's a concatenated field, hence it had values separated by semi-colons.

[image: pic of the columns being used on the list]

Comment: Is this a multiple selection lookup column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below JSON column formatting code for your extended lookup column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField, ';', '\n')"
}
```

For more information, check this article: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting)

**Output**:

[image]

If you want to keep `;` at the end of each item in lookup column value, use this JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField, ';', ';\n')"
}
```