# JSON to wrap text after ";" from a lookup AND delete blank spaces

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a column "Action Status" which is looking up multiple values in a separate Actions table.

The first screen shot shows how the data appears without applying any JSON coding (I'm a complete novice with this) and the second what it looks like when I've used one of the suggested codes (online) to wrap the text after ";".

The problem is  that some of the returned values are blank and appear as "; ;" in my list and therefore when the wrap coding is applied it leaves a blank row for the empty values (see second screenshot).

How do I wrap after ";" AND delete the blank values please?

JSON code I've used:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "=replaceAll(@currentField, '; ', '\n')"
}
```

Without JSON formatting:

[image]

With JSON formatting:

[image]

Comment: Try using expression for `txtContent` like: `=replaceAll(replaceAll(@currentField, '; ; ', '; '), '; ', '\n')`. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SharePoint JSON column formatting like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=replaceAll(replaceAll(@currentField, '; ; ', '; '), '; ', '\n')"
}
```

**References**:

1. [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting)
2. [Wrap text in a column after a character (;) using JSON](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307003/wrap-text-in-a-column-after-a-character-using-json/307004#307004)
3. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you, that works

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Please [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Keep using this platform for asking any questions related to SharePoint, thank you!